# Clicking a link updates list view web part

Tags: list-view, page-viewer-web-part

I have a page viewer webpart with HTML.  It has links in it.  These links are embedded in a map.  When clicking a link, I want that link to update a list viewer webpart by setting a filter in it.

Would I be able to achieve this by setting the target to equal that of the webpart zone ID?  And if so, how do I pass the additional filter data to the list view webpart so it filters?

Answer (score 0):

Pass extra filter information as query string parameters, something like

```
http://website/yourdestinationpage?webpartID={zoneID}&filter1={filter1value}
```

Also check filter web parts, many type of filtering can be done out of the box.
[Work with filter Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-filter-Web-Parts-4d052e5d-c5e9-437b-aa36-ae50b6c2678f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: I can do that for a page viewer webpart, but to send the filter directly to the webpart I need to use the Inpl.js script.

Comment: You can also connect web parts and send values.